# std::atomic<double> on Armv7 (RPi2) and alignment/bus errors

Tags: c++, c++11

I use std::atomic to protect access to float variables that may be assessed from multiple threads. This works well on x86, but crashes on ARMv7 (RPi2).

I'm compiling on x86 with VS2012, Xcode and GCC4.9.2 with no problems. Code that use the atomic values when I compile for ARMv7 (also GCC4.9.2) crashes with 'Bus Error' (which you get when data is not properly aligned on ARM).

Is this a bug in GCC or am I doing something wrong?

Related question: ['Bus Error' on ARMv6 when working with doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35071659/1151329)

Comment: Sounds like bug of the compiler, but without the code, we cannot help. Also, consider to avoid `atomic`. If accessed frequently from different threads, that really kills your performance (since each thread must update the whole cache line each time another thread has written the `atomic`).

Comment: It's quite possible it's a gcc bug, but we don't know if you did something wrong, so show your code and how you  compile it.

Comment: @walter: I will pull out some code and prepare an example ASAP. What alternatives would there be to atomic<double> that would not kill performance?