# 'Bus Error' on ARMv6 when working with doubles

Tags: c++, arm

I'm creating a C++ program for ARMv6 which crashes with BUS ERROR. Using GDB I have traced the problem to the following code

```
double d = *(double*)pData; pData += sizeof(int64_t);  // char *pData
```

The program goes through a received message and has to extract some double values using the above code. The received message has several fields, some doubles some not.

On x86 architectures this works fine, but on ARM I get the 'bus error'. So, I suspect my problem is alignment of data -- the double fields have to be aligned to word boundaries in memory on the ARM architecture.

I have tried the following as a fix, which did not work (still got the error):

```
int64_t i = *(int64_t*)pData;
double d = *((double*)&i);
```

The following worked (so far):

```
double d = 0;
memcpy(&d, pData, sizeof(double));
```

Is using 'memcpy' the best approach? Or, is there a better way?

*In my case I do not have control over the packing of the data in the buffer or the order of the fields in the message.*

Related question: [std::atomic<double> on Armv7 (RPi2) and alignment/bus errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30523825/1151329)

Comment: You've answered your question yourself. To access double data, you need to be present at aligned memory address, and no cast tricks can help - you really need to **put** the data on aligned address.

Comment: If you can control the buffer, you might want to pad non-double data so that doubles are always properly aligned. Than by aligining the buffer itself, you can avoid copying.

Comment: @SergeyA thx, I receive the data over a TCP stream and I'm trying to parse the data inline

Comment: Yeah - with such protocols, I try hard to put all the multi-byte fields at positions where they will be aligned, even if I occasionally have to stuff in the odd filler byte.

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage, I guessed that much. But are you in control of actually producing the buffer?

Comment: @SergeyA, I read the data directly into a buffer and I would prefer not to have to read field by field

Comment: @SergeyA, using memcpy seems to work, but my question is whether using memcpy is the correct approach in my case, or if there might be a better approach

Comment: You know `int64_t`s have the same alignment requirements as `double`s on ARM, right?

Comment: @immibis, yes, I figured as much when I still got the same error with the casting to int64_t

Comment: @ArnoDuvenhage, since you do not have control over buffer contents, memcpy is the only way to do what you are doing. Sad state of affairs it is.

Comment: not sad, just realities of life.  you are taking a performance hit either way.  arm, x86, etc.  you can often on arm disable the alignment fault and accept the performance hit.  depends on the arm architecture though.

Comment: `memcpy` is the only portable method to do what you're doing.  Obviously you cannot use `double *` to read data that is not already aligned to a `double` boundary;  however even if it were aligned correctly, that code may also violate the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the `atomic<double>` question

Comment: I had a similar error with atomic<double> which could not be explained. I'm pretty sure the 'trivial' copies within atomic for doubles are also not aligned - will check the STL source to confirm .. Only a problem on ARM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using 'memcpy' the best approach?

In general it's the *only* correct approach, unless you're targeting a single ABI in which no type requires greater than 1-byte alignment.

The C++ standard is rather verbose, so I'll quote the C standard expressing the same thing much more succinctly:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

There it is: that ever-present spectre of undefined behaviour. Even an x86 compiler is perfectly well allowed to break into your house and rub jam into your hair while you sleep instead of loading that data the way you expect, if its ABI says so.

One thing to note, though, is that modern compilers tend to be clever enough that correctness doesn't necessarily come at the cost of performance. Let's flesh out that example code:

```
#include <string.h>

double func(char *data) {
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, data, sizeof d);
    return d;
}
```

...and throw it at a compiler:

```
$ clang -target arm -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -O1 -S test.c
...
func:                                   @ @func
        .fnstart
@ BB#0:
        push    {r4, r5, r11, lr}
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        mov     r2, r0
        ldrb    r1, [r0, #3]
        ldrb    r3, [r0, #2]
        ldrb    r12, [r0]
        ldrb    lr, [r0, #1]
        ldrb    r4, [r2, #4]!
        orr     r5, r3, r1, lsl #8
        ldrb    r3, [r2, #2]
        ldrb    r2, [r2, #3]
        ldrb    r0, [r0, #5]
        orr     r1, r12, lr, lsl #8
        orr     r2, r3, r2, lsl #8
        orr     r0, r4, r0, lsl #8
        orr     r1, r1, r5, lsl #16
        orr     r0, r0, r2, lsl #16
        str     r1, [sp]
        str     r0, [sp, #4]
        vpop    {d0}
        pop     {r4, r5, r11, pc}
```

OK, so it's playing things safe with a bytewise `memcpy`; at least it's inlined. But hey, ARMv6 does at least support unaligned word and halfword accesses if the CPU is configured appropriately - let's tell the compiler we're cool with that:

```
$ clang -target arm -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -O1 -S -munaligned-access test.c
...
func:                                   @ @func
        .fnstart
@ BB#0:
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        ldr     r1, [r0]
        ldr     r0, [r0, #4]
        str     r0, [sp, #4]
        str     r1, [sp]
        vpop    {d0}
        bx      lr
```

There we go, that's about the best you can do with just integer word loads. Now, what if we compile it for something a bit newer?

```
$ clang -target arm -march=armv7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -O1 -S test.c
...
func:                                   @ @func
        .fnstart
@ BB#0:
        vld1.8  {d0}, [r0]
        bx      lr
```

I can guarantee that, even on a machine where it would "work", no undefined-behaviour-hackery would correctly load that unaligned double in fewer than one instructions. Note that NEON is the key player here - `vld1` only requires the base address to be aligned to the element size, so for 8-bit elements it can never be unaligned. In the more general case (say, if it were a `long long` instead of a `double`) you might still need `-munaligned-access` to convince the compiler as before.

For comparison, let's just see how everyone's favourite mutant-grandchild-of-a-1970s-calculator-chip fares as well:

```
clang -O1 -S test.c
...
func:                                   # @func
# BB#0:
        movl    4(%esp), %eax
        fldl    (%eax)
        retl
```

Yup, the correct code still also looks like the best code.

Comment: why did you not use the -munaligned-access option in the armv7 case?

Comment: Explanation added. As it happens, I'm used to the GCC builds I normally use having unaligned access enabled by default for v7 targets. Upon further investigation (with different types) this Clang (3.7.1, Arch Linux i686) doesn't, but I failed to notice because it doesn't affect the example I wanted to make ;)